# Overriding member variables in C++

Tags: c++

Consider the below code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public :
    int i;
    int j;
    void print() {
        cout << i << "\t" << j << endl;
    }
};


class B : public A {
public:
    int f;
    int g;
    int i;
    
    void print() {
        A::print();
        cout << f << "\t" << g<<endl;
    
    }


};


int main()
{
    B obj;
    obj.f = 1;
    obj.g = 2;
    obj.i = 3;
    obj.A::i = 4;
    obj.j = 5;
    obj.print();
    cout << obj.i;
   
}
```

The output is :

```
4       5
1       2
3
```

It is clear that the print function has printed the value of i that is related to the parent class but not the overriding one. My question is why the print function has printed the i of the parent class not the overriding one ?

Comment: You can't _"`override`"_ variables from the base class, you can use your class local ones in an overidden function though.

Comment: Note: The duplicate was found by pasting the title, "Overriding member variables in C++", into Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You printed `i` via `A`'s (the parent class's) `print` function. Your class has two `i`s, and `A`'s `print` only knows where to find one of them (the one from `A`). If you want to print `B`'s `i`, it has to be done in a `B` method (that knows where to find it).

You *could* make a `virtual` accessor method on `A` that provides access to `i`, and have `B` override it, while `A`'s `print` uses it (rather than direct accessing `i`), so it can see the `i` from `B`, but that's the best you'll get. It works because methods can be `virtual` (looked up dynamically based on runtime type), and if the accessor is virtual on `A` and overridden on `B`, the `B` method will be found when `A`'s `print` calls it, and `B`'s method sees the definitions in `B`.